# Can't initialize a template constexpr member variable with a lambda

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

I am making a container that forces itself to have size that is the next power of 2 of the size that the user wants. This is calculated at compile time. I tried to do it using a lambda but failed. The following code compiles and works as intended:

```
template <typename T, size_t MinSize>
class Power2Container
{
private:
    T* Buffer;
    static constexpr size_t NextPowerOf2()
    {
        size_t v = MinSize;
        v--;
        v |= v >> 1;
        v |= v >> 2;
        v |= v >> 4;
        v |= v >> 8;
        v |= v >> 16;
        v++;
        return v;
    }
    static constexpr size_t ActualSize = NextPowerOf2();
};
```

However, trying to use a lambda fails with error C2440, saying it cannot convert the lambda to `const size_t`:

```
static constexpr size_t ActualSize = []() {
            size_t v = MinSize;
            v--;
            v |= v >> 1;
            v |= v >> 2;
            v |= v >> 4;
            v |= v >> 8;
            v |= v >> 16;
            v++;
            return v;
        };
```

I tried `[=]`,`[&]`, writing `constexpr` before the curly braces, `-> size_t` and `-> const size_t`. None of them are willing to compile.

I am using Visual Studio 2019, latest version, compiling with c++ 17.

Comment: You forgot to call the lambda it seems, so `}();` on the last line.

Comment: This is what I already put to my records: some variable, init. with immediately called lambda, type mismatch -> most times the missing `()` at the end (to actually call the lambda). :-)

Comment: @cigien that was it. You can write this as an answer and I will accept it.